# How to dynamically point to a static asset leveraging the path lookup in Vite/Vue3? Using Typescript paths in dynamic URLs to assets

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, assets, idioms, vite

It is my understanding that [as per the docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#new-url-url-import-meta-url), following is the idiomatic way to dynamically generate an url to a static asset with Vite/Vue3:

```
URL(`../../assets/${name}.png`, import.meta.url).href
```

However, I would like to leverage the TypeScript import lookup locations as per `tsconfig.json`

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
```

Trying a simple

```
URL(`@/assets/${name}.png`, import.meta.url).href
```

will just put the `@` in the url. Using `src/assets/${name}.png` works but defeats the purpose.

It also seems that `URL` will gladly generate any kind of string without checking whether it points to a resource that could actually be loaded by the browser.

What is the idiomatic way to dynamically point to a static asset leveraging the path lookup?

Comment: The docs pointed out that `Vite doesn't need to process this code at all during development!`. So I think the `@` will not work here. Why don't you use the traditional way - import the file in typescript code? `import SomeImage from "@/assets/images/some-image.png";`

Comment: I don't think `import from` that works for dynamically generated (lists of) image names, does it?

Comment: Oh. I missed that point. `import` will not work with dynamically generated links. Dynamic import `import()` can work with dynamically generated links but we can't combine it with aliases. So I think you can not use aliases in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `new URL` won't work because this code isn't statically replaced by Vite, so you won't be able to use your aliases.

You can use [`import.meta.globEager`](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import) instead.

```
const images = import.meta.globEager('@/assets/*.png', { as: 'url' })
```

This will give you an object, which keys are the paths to the images and the values are their URLs.

An example would be:

```
const images = import.meta.globEager('@/assets/*.png', { as: 'url' });

function assetUrl(name: string): string {
  return images[Object.keys(images).find((path) => path.endsWith(name))]?.default;
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Two nitpicks though: 1) strict TS wants me to assert the index to not be undefined. 2) checking just for `endsWith` has issues with names that are suffixes of one another. That can be fixed with a more specific check, but once a `**`-glob is involved, I think there are inevitable corner-cases.

Comment: I actually wanted to simplify for the example, but you can sort by length the keys so `endsWith` finds the shortest occurrence first - which would solve a few edge cases. I did that myself when using `import.meta.glob` for finding page components for Inertia.js.